# Extract values of a variable occurring multiple times in a file

Tags: unix

I have to extract value of a variable which occurs multiple times in a file. for example, I have a text file `abc.txt` . There is a variable `result`. Suppose value of `result` in first line is `2`, in third line it is `55` and in last line it is `66`.
Then my desired output should be :

```
result:2,55,66
```

I am new in unix so I could not figure out how to do this. Please help

The contents of text file can be as follows:

```
R$#$#%$W%^BHGF, result=2,
fsdfsdsgf 
VSDF$TR$R,result=55
fsdf4r54
result=66
```

Comment: Is the abc.txt a shell script to have variables ?

Comment: abc.txt is a text file, I need to write a code in another unix file (suppose xyz.sh) to extract the values

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) code :

```
awk -F'(,| |^)result=' '
    /result=/{
        gsub(",", "", $2)
        v = $2
        str = (str) ? str","v : v
    }
    END{print "result:"str}
' abc.txt
```

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) code :

```
perl -lane '
    push @arr, $& if /\bresult=\K\d+/;
    END{print "result:" . join ",", @arr}
' abc.txt
```

Output :

```
result:2,55,66
```

Comment: If the content in the file is:  foobar=444,VFGRWTRWGTWY%,result=2,%^%ERTG: result=55  Then it will work?